# Attempting to create an unmanaged thread from managed class

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, unmanaged, managed

Here's my scenario.

```
void SecondThread
{
    //more code
}

private: System::Void Button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    //where I click my button event
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&SecondThread, 0, 0, NULL);
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to use a pointer to an unmanaged function from a .NET function.
It gives this error.

**"A pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class."**

Anyone know how I can get rid of it? Also, **I'm not interested** starting a thread as this because I need to use unmanaged code:

*ThreadStart *myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(this, repeat);
trd->Start();*

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a member function. Use a static function outside of the class. Pass the class a argument to the threadfunc and declare the function as friend to the class if you need to access private members. You may need to use gcroot to wrap the class instance.

Comment: But my SecondThread also accesses the members from the UI I'm using, so if I use it statically outside, then I won't be able to access them anymore...

Comment: Why not. You can pass a state object that contains reference to the UI as well. Also you should be careful when calling the UI from a different thread without Invoke or BeginInvoke

Comment: And another point - If the work you do is really managed work you should do what you requested no to do and use the Thread object